# relationship between points plotted in python and ram

Tags: python, time, graph, ram

I am trying to max out my RAM usage by plotting points in Python via the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(1,n,1)
plt.plot(x,x)
```

I Have 16 GB RAM, which maxes out when n is in between 100 million - 800 million. Supposing I do not change anything about my code or computer, but change 16 GB to 32 GB RAM, what will be the maximum value of n now?

I did'nt really tried anything since I don't have 32 GB RAM avaialble, but on searching here and there the most common answer was that the relation is not linear, but they did'nt specified what it was then.

Comment: You don't need 32GB RAM to do the test. Just see how much VM the process is using.

Comment: @Barmar Can you expand on this a bit more?

Comment: On Linux you can use `ps` or `top` to see the virtual memory size of the python process (it's the `VSIZE` column). You can treat that as the amount of RAM that would be used if you had enough RAM.